# Nothing to be done for `internal-bundle-compile' Theos

Tags: objective-c, package, theos, building

Just yesterday I started getting a message in terminal when I tried to compile a tweak. It said

```
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `internal-bundle-compile'.
```

The .deb is still built, but when I install it on my device, the preference bundle doesn't show up in settings.

```
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `internal-bundle-compile'.
Making stage for tweak test...
Making stage in prefs...
Making stage for bundle prefs...
dpkg-deb: building package `com.myname.test' in `./com.myname.test_0.0.1-14_iphoneos-arm.deb'.
```

I know there's no problem with my code, because I get these results on tweaks I've successfully built in the past, and have not modified since. Been trying to figure this out for several hours with no luck.

Comment: Try make clean before rebuilding

Comment: Make clean doesn't change the results :(